# cURL is very slow on PHP 7 but not PHP 5

Tags: php, curl

cURL seems to be significantly slower for me using PHP7.0.11 than it is when just running the request from the command line, or when run within PHP5.6.24. I'm testing it using the following code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://i.imgur.com/H1zC601.gif");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl));
```

In both PHP5 and PHP7's CLI interpreter, and in PHP5 I get

```
array(26) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(31) "https://i.imgur.com/H1zC601.gif"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "image/gif"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(597)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(204)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(1.260002)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.060424)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.068474)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.089705)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(34327108)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(27243693)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(34327108)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.098354)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(15) "151.101.124.193"
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(443)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(14) "my IP"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(44555)
}
```

While when running PHP7, I get

```
array(26) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(31) "https://i.imgur.com/H1zC601.gif"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "image/gif"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(609)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(61)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(16.875167)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.252648)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.260626)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.280489)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(34327108)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(2034178)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(34327108)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.288715)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(15) "151.101.124.193"
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(443)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(14) "my IP"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(55559)
}
```

The important part being total_time, which is 1.3 seconds in PHP 5 but 16.9s in PHP 7.

When a timeout is set on the request, the number of bytes received is proportional to the timeout - the data is being transferred very slowly, rather than there being some obstruction that is preventing anything from being transferred for a while, then the whole thing being transferred in one go.

The server is running Debian, and I can't seem to reproduce the issue on my Fedora local machine.

Comment: Is this on the same server?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, all the tests (PHP7, PHP5 and command line curl (which I don't have exact numbers for, but is roughly the same speed as PHP5)) were performed on the same server.

Comment: Are you running this in a Virtual Machine?

Comment: @Sherif no, it's a dedicated server with plenty of resources. I can reproduce the results every time I run them.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue with PHP 7 on Debian Stretch. I noticed high sys-cpu times: 0.07s user 10.02s system 92% cpu 10.859 total

Issue was solved after disable transparent_hugepage:

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
```

It does not effect curl downloads directly, but slows down php memory allocations. See: https://serverfault.com/questions/780555/how-to-troubleshoot-high-load-caused-by-php7

Answer (score 0):

To me, this just looks like a network latency issue or bandwidth issue. If you examine the `speed_download` between the two you'll see that one is downloading significantly faster than the other. The first result using PHP 5/7-CLI shows `"speed_download" => float(27243693)` while the second shows `"speed_download" => float(2034178)`, while they both have an identical content length `"download_content_length" => float(34327108)`.

So the first one is downloading a ~32.7MB file at ~25.9MB/sec, while the second is downloading the same file at ~1.9MB/sec. Obviously the second would take a lot longer.

Comment: But both are running on the same server, and I can reliably reproduce the results, so it's not just some random spike.

Comment: I believe you, but there's no evidence to indicate that PHP is at fault here. You might have some network configuration somewhere that's throttling the inbound bandwidth by port or even by process if it's software-based. It's unclear what caused the problem, but the data points to a bandwidth issue, not a PHP one.

Comment: To put it another way, if the speed of transfer is slow, PHP cannot possibly be expected to finish any faster than it takes to complete the transfer at any rate. However, the question of why is one version of PHP downloading the file slower than another version of PHP remains completely unknown without further investigating the networking configuration on that system. I can tell you that I just ran your code on both PHP 5 and PHP 7 locally and got consistent results when downloading at the same speed. So no indication it's PHP at large. Must be something specific to your setup.

Comment: I'm aware that the download speed is slow, but I'm trying to figure out why that is. You're probably right that it's a configuration issue, but I don't know where to start looking - there have been no attempts to alter bandwidth for particular process, so I can't think what could be slowing down just PHP7.

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue with curl onPHP 7.0.12 i run on  both cli and fpm mode and download very slow speed, the speed degrade from 100Mbps to only 1~2 Mbps/s, i switch to php 5.6 and problem resolve, so it is not network issue,i am sure
Hoping my info will help someone

Answer (score 0):

You can see the php-curl versions like this:

`php5 --ri curl
 php7 --ri curl`

Sometimes, The lower version can cause it.