# Bad performance in the cURL call on the same server

Tags: php, performance, curl

Why just few concurrency can cause block when cURL call on the same server

### Example

phpdebug.com

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://phpdebug2.com",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

phpdebug2.com

```
<?php
echo "application2";
```

### Apache ab  test result

```
ab -n 10 -c 2 http://phpdebug.com/

Requests per second:    198.93 [#/sec] (mean) 
Time per request:       10.054 [ms] (mean) 
Time per request:       5.027 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests) 
Transfer rate:          33.80 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

---

```
ab -n 10 -c 3 http://phpdebug.com/

Requests per second:    60.42 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       49.648 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       16.550 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          10.27 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

---

```
ab -n 10 -c 4 http://phpdebug.com/

Requests per second:    17.68 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       226.226 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       56.557 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          3.00 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

---

```
ab -n 10 -c 5 http://phpdebug.com/

Benchmarking phpdebug.com (be patient)...apr_pollset_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
```

1. Why the **Requests per second** drop so fast?
2. How to optimize this situation when cURL call on the same server?

Comment: Wonder if this isn't better placed at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ? Unsure.

Comment: what happens when you run TOP?

Comment: @NevilleK As usual,several php-fpm show in seconds.

Comment: Can you see which of the two servers is consuming the resources? phpdebug, or phpdebug2?

Comment: @NevilleK Sorry,I can't distinguish them.

Comment: The problem is that you could be bottlenecked by a whole range of different things - one or both the web apps could be misconfigured in Apache, the requests might be routed to the public internet and back, etc. Try using https://github.com/nette/tracy or similar to work out what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

Several thought on the issue:

1. Is including the other file an option to avoid cUrl request? Also you could just pass data somehow else, like via database, for instance.
2. Looks like `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` does not need to be there is you're running on the same server, rigth?
3. I would also suggest lowering the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` by the approximate script run time, as there is no network (or almost no network) delay.
4. You could try calling the IP directly, without the domain name. This should skip the DNS lookup and speed up a bit.
5. To see where the process is going slower, you could also `strace` the process. Here's [how](https://derickrethans.nl/what-is-php-doing.html)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using PHP7, please check for high sys cpu utilisation. Try disabling huge pages with:

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
```

See: [cURL is very slow on PHP 7 but not PHP 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671399/curl-is-very-slow-on-php-7-but-not-php-5/45509402#45509402)